# jQuery - Select by multiple different selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select and change src of a div which has a class of `heruyeresmi` and src of `http://www.example.org`

Tried this without any luck

```
$(".heruyeresmi,['src'='http://www.example.org']").attr("src","http://www.example.com");
```

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: `$(".heruyeresmi[src='http://www.example.org']")`, remove `,` it denotes multiple selector https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: A `div` should not have a `src` attribute. Do you mean select element having `src` attribute with value set to `"http://www.example.org"` that is a child element of `.heruyeresmi` `$(".heruyeresmi [src='http://www.example.org']")`?

Comment: No its actually image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove comma in selector and quotes surrounding attribute name

```
$(".heruyeresmi[src='http://www.example.org']")
```